# В чем разница двух строчек кода с объявлением переменной?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Объясните в чем разница вот этих двух строчек:

1. `public float Speed = 10f;`
2. `public float Speed = 10;`

Comment: Второй автоматом конвертнётся во float. Но лучше так не писать

Comment: ок спасибо огромное

Comment: @АлексейШиманский поясните почему так лучше не писать? сколько живу - считаю что явное указание типа только плюс... или вы именно про длинный способ записи а не сокращенный?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков во втором примере в конце не указано `f`, так лучше не писать, как раз потому, что не указано явно

Comment: Да, спасибо, видимо я по диагонали читаю с утра, прочел ровно противоположное :) ("запись с указанием типа лучше не делать"(с буквой f на конце))... :(

Comment: "явное лучше неявного", хотя это из "дзен Питона", но сюда тоже подходит )

Answer (score 1):

С комментариями о "явном" и "неявном" не согласен ибо тип задается и это уже само по себе "явно".

Рассмотрим:

```
public float Speed = 10f; // float /тип указан явно 2 раза
public float Speed = 10;  // float /тип указан явно
```

В обьявлении глобальных разницы никакой.

А вот в локальных переменных ситуация интереснее:

```
var speed = 10;     // int
var speed = 10.0;   // double
var speed = 10f;    // float /тип указан явно что бы получить float
var speed = 10.0f;  // float /тип указан явно что бы получить float

float speed = 10; // float /тип указан явно
float speed = 10f;// float /тип указан явно 2 раза
```

f писать желательно. Но имхо - не обязательно если уж тип задается явно при обьявлении переменной. При использовании var - f писать обязательно потому что получишь не тот тип который тебе необходим.

Так же стоит заметить что в разных компаниях свой кодстайл и если по кодстайлу ты должен обязательно писать f даже указывая тип данных при обьявлении переменных - так делать будет нужно просто что бы не отклонятся от кодстайла.

почему можно предположить что всегда нужно использовать f? Да чисто что бы меньше задумываться. Но лично я не считаю плохой практикой не использование f.

Comment: Дело в том, что скажем при рефакторинге могут заменить `float` на `var`, а справа забудут `f` дописать к константе и тогда "сюрприз будет". То есть нужно учитывать не только текущее состояние кода, но и возможные изменения при дальнейшем его развитии. Из этих соображений лучше не отдавать этот вопрос на самотёк и всё явно прописать везде.

Comment: @CrazyElf имхо - при обьявлении локальных переменных использовать явный тип это в принципе моветон просто потому что это занимает больше места. Поэтому в локальных переменных всегда будет выходить писать 10f. А значит и ситуация поломать при рефакторинге будет равнятся практически нулю. А вот в глобальных переменных ситуация такая что невозможно использовать var и там сломать при рефакторинге даже теоретически нереально. Поэтому считаю это надуманной проблемой

Comment: Да, по большому счёту проблема надуманная, но я всё же за однообразие. Тут пишем, а тут не пишем - не люблю такое. В выражениях пишем, в локальных константах пишем, а в глобальных константах не пишем - ну, мне такое не нравится. Стиль должен быть единым, чем меньше условий и правил - тем лучше. Хотя в выражениях не должно быть "магических чисел", только константы, но всяко бывает. Так что я за принцип "пишем везде" - он просто проще и понятнее.